# chrome 22 and css (negative left) accessibitlity issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, accessibility

I am currently developing an interface accessible AA. By updating Chrome to version 22, all CSS left:-9999999999999999999px no longer work.

This project is based on a navigation tab.

Is there another way to hide content while remaining accessible to screen readers without degrading the display?

Thank you for your help.

**I found the solution: left:-9999999px is the maximum negative value accepted by Chrome 22**
Sorry I can't post Answer...

Comment: Add a basic example of the code that doesn't work to make useful answers possible.

Comment: I found the solution:
left:-9999999px is the maximum negative value accepted by Chrome 22

Comment: Stick to approx. -9999px and you'll avoid problems. [Replacing the -9999px hack (new image replacement)](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/) advantage is yet to be demonstrated but it also works and doesn't harm afaik

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the clip method. Assign class="hidden" to the element you want to hide:

```
.hidden { 
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

Then remove that class when you want to show the content. There's more detail on this and various other methods here: 
http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/hiding-content-for-accessibility

Comment: Thank's for your link, i found some interesting technics.